# Spring Data Neo4j 4 Pageable with org.neo4j.ogm.session.Session.query

Tags: cypher, spring-data-neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4

Is it possible in Spring Data Neo4j 4 to use `Pageable` with `org.neo4j.ogm.session.Session` like `session.query(characteristicCypher, parameters);`

If so, could you please show an example ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  `org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable` is not compatible with the OGM `Session`.

You can use the OGM native `org.neo4j.ogm.cypher.query.Pagination` with `Session` though. You can see examples of how to use that in the [OGM test source](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-ogm/blob/master/core/src/test/java/org/neo4j/ogm/persistence/examples/ingredients/IngredientsIntegrationTest.java).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is it okay to translate for example `new PageRequest(0, 1000)` into `SKIP 0 LIMIT 1000` or I should do a some math on `PageRequest.page`, `PageRequest.size` params before translate it into the corresponding Cypher `SKIP` and `LIMIT` ?

Comment: You'll need to do some maths as what is returned from the call to `Session` does not return a Page type of object but instead just an `Iterable`. You'll need to wrap that result up so subsequent calls retrieve what you want.